# How to build Clojure program using command: lein do test, uberjar, pom

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I'm struggling to build the program using:

`lein do test, uberjar, pom`

And then the program should be runnable using the following command:

```
java -jar target/{artifactid}-{version}-standalone.jar
```

I'm having a simple code to sort String, the project is made in maven, and I have added Clojure dependency to the pom.xml
Now I'm running this in IntelliJ IDEA using the Cursive plugin but I guess this is not what I want to have.

I'm totally new in this field so any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: The pom is something you don't really need, except for publishing your
library. Building the uberjar and running it, the way you described is
about right. Could you please be more specific what the error is you are
getting?  Is it related to the uberjar?  Or is it a runtime problem? Can
you share a MVE?

Comment: It is difficult for me to describe this problem since I don't really understand this uberjar build process. 

I have a simple code that checks if the string contains specific characters in it and it works fine in IntelliJ when using "Load to REPL" and then calling the checking functions. But I was asked to build the app using mentioned commands and I don't really know how to start.

Is there any "step by step" tutorial you can recommend, or could you go through this with me?

Comment: Does `lein uberjar` give you errors?  Does `java jar
**/*-standalone.jar` give you errors?  More prose frankly will not help
us helping you solve this problem (asking for tutorials is frown upon on
SO). So please add what actual problems you are facing: share the code
if you can and add the errors, logs, stacktraces, ... and where you get
them.

Comment: As cfrick mentions, please provide the code you are using, the exact command you are running, and the errors you get.  Best if you can share your repository so we can help.